# Create type instance dynamically by using assembly name and class Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection

I want to dyanmically  create an instance of interface object by using Activator class .
Below is the class which implements the interface

```
     namespace ReportService.ReportWriters
    {
        class ExcelWriter : IReportWriter
        {


        }

}
```

I tried below code

```
IReportWriter oIreportService = (IReportWriter)Activator.CreateInstanceFrom("ExcelWriter", "ReportService.ReportWriters");
```

The above code is not working.Can anyone help me on this..

Comment: Can you please comment why you decided to pass arguments to `CreateInstanceFrom` the way you show in your sample? It somewhat unclear what exactly you don't understand from MSDN article on `CreateInstanceFrom`.

Comment: So you mean the arguments should be in reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

You have the parameter order incorrect and you need to use the fully qualified type name and the path to the DLL file.

MSDN has this signature for CreateInstanceFrom

```
public static ObjectHandle CreateInstanceFrom(
string assemblyFile,
string typeName )
```

So your code should look like this:

```
IReportWriter oIreportService = (IReportWriter)Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(PathToReportWritersDll, "ReportService.ReportWriters.ExcelWriter");
```

Also you may want to use "as" to cast for a safe cast when doing reflection.

```
IReportWriter oIreportService = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(PathToReportWritersDll, "ReportService.ReportWriters.ExcelWriter") as IReportWriter;
```